In ASP.NET Core Blazor with a download controller, is there a way to update a progress bar back to the page?
I would like to be able to update a percent progress bar of to show how far along in reading files my controller is.
This is my controller for downloading:
[HttpGet("multiple/{*pathsInSharedDrive}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFiles(string pathsInSharedDrive)
{
    string[] paths = pathsInSharedDrive.Split(',');

    var sharedDrivePath = _configuration.GetSection("PathStrings")["SecureFileShare"];

    var tempZipPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".zip");

    try
    {
        using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(tempZipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    var relativePath = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(path, relativePath);
                }

                else if (Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        var relativePath = file.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                        zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, relativePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var zipBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(tempZipPath);

        return File(zipBytes, "application/zip", "BH-files.zip");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempZipPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(tempZipPath);
        }
    }
}

I have been using navigate to to get to the controller
NavManager.NavigateTo($@"api/download/multiple/{controllerParameter}", forceLoad: true);

Can I send back information form the controller to the page that tells it x file out of y files?
Like in the foreach I simply put an I variable that returns back to my page each iteration to slowly update the progress bar on the page.
I tried something like this with a Javascript:
    [HttpGet("multiple/{*pathsInSharedDrive}")]
    public async Task DownloadFiles(string pathsInSharedDrive)
    {
        string[] paths = pathsInSharedDrive.Split(',');
        var sharedDrivePath = _configuration.GetSection("PathStrings")["SecureFileShare"];

        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=BH-files.zip");

        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            var progressInfo = new ProgressInfo();

            // Calculate total size
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(sharedDrivePath, path);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    progressInfo.TotalSize += new FileInfo(fullPath).Length;
                }
                else if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    progressInfo.TotalSize += Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(f => new FileInfo(f).Length);
                }
            }

            Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Size", progressInfo.TotalSize.ToString());

            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(sharedDrivePath, path);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    var relativePath = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
                    await AddFileToArchive(archive, fullPath, relativePath, progressInfo);
                }
                else if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        var relativePath = file.Substring(fullPath.Length + 1);
                        await AddFileToArchive(archive, file, relativePath, progressInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task AddFileToArchive(ZipArchive archive, string filePath, string entryName, ProgressInfo progressInfo)
    {
        var entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryName);

        using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
            progressInfo.ProcessedSize += fileStream.Length;
            Response.Headers["X-Processed-Size"] = progressInfo.ProcessedSize.ToString();
            await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
    }

js
window.downloadWithProgress = function (url, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';

        xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
            var totalSize = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Size');
            var processedSize = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Processed-Size');
            if (totalSize && processedSize) {
                var percentComplete = (processedSize / totalSize) * 100;
                DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('SecureFileShare', 'UpdateProgress', percentComplete);
            }
        };

        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/zip' });
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                a.remove();
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Download failed'));
            }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject(new Error('Network error'));
        };

        xhr.send();
    });
};

On the page, I call the Javascript:
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadWithProgress", url, "BH-files.zip");

This worked for downloading but
var processedSize = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Processed-Size');

was not updating.
There has to be a better way. Let me know what you think.

You can use real-time communication technology such as SignalR to let the server push information to the client, there by meeting the need for real-time progress updates, and thus updating the progress bar in real time during the file download process. In this process, the SignalR Hub is used to receive and broadcast progress update messages, and the front end connects to the Hub through the SignalR client to receive these messages and update the UI. The following is a single path example for your reference:
Controller:
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<MyChatHub> _hubContext;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public HomeController(IHubContext<MyChatHub> hubContext, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _configuration = configuration;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFiles(string pathsInSharedDrive)
        {
            string[] paths = pathsInSharedDrive.Split(',');
            var sharedDrivePath = _configuration.GetSection("PathStrings")["SecureFileShare"];

            var tempZipPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".zip");

            try
            {
                using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(tempZipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
                {
                    var totalSize = CalculateTotalSize(paths);

                    foreach (var path in paths)
                    {
                        var fullPath = Path.Combine( path);

                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                        {
                            await AddFileToArchive(zipArchive, fullPath, Path.GetFileName(fullPath), totalSize);
                        }
                        else if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
                        {
                            var files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                            foreach (var file in files)
                            {
                                await AddFileToArchive(zipArchive, file, file.Substring(fullPath.Length + 1), totalSize);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgress", 100);

                var zipBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(tempZipPath);

                return File(zipBytes, "application/zip", "BH-files.zip");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempZipPath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(tempZipPath);
                }
            }
        }

        private long CalculateTotalSize(string[] paths)
        {
            long totalSize = 0;
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(path);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    totalSize += new FileInfo(fullPath).Length;
                }
                else if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    totalSize += Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(f => new FileInfo(f).Length);
                }
            }
            return totalSize;
        }

        private async Task AddFileToArchive(ZipArchive archive, string filePath, string entryName, long totalSize)
        {
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryName);

            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                long bytesWritten = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesWritten += bytesRead;

                 
                    int percentComplete = (int)((double)bytesWritten / totalSize * 100);
                    await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgress", percentComplete);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Js:
window.downloadWithProgress = function (url, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';

        xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
            var totalSize = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Size');
            var processedSize = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Processed-Size');
            if (totalSize && processedSize) {
                var percentComplete = (processedSize / totalSize) * 100;
                DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorApp3', 'UpdateProgress', percentComplete);
            }
        };

        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/zip' });
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                a.remove();
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Download failed'));
            }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject(new Error('Network error'));
        };

        xhr.send();
    });
};

And I simulated the local path:
@page "/download"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@rendermode InteractiveServer


<h3>Download Progress</h3>

<div>
    <button @onclick="StartDownload">Start Download</button>
</div>

<div>
    <progress id="progressBar" max="100" value="@progress"></progress>
    <span>@progress %</span>
</div>

@code {
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private int progress;

    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/MyChatHub"))
            .Build();

        _hubConnection.On<int>("ReceiveProgress", p =>
        {
            progress = p;
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });

        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task StartDownload()
    {
        try
        {
            var directoryPath = "C:/Users/v-yuningduan/Pictures/Screenshots"; 

            var encodedPath = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(directoryPath); 

            var url = $"api/Home?pathsInSharedDrive={encodedPath}";
       
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadWithProgress", url, "Screenshots.zip");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_hubConnection != null)
        {
            await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./JS/Downloadmethod.js");
        }
    }
}

After completion:


For anyone in future, I was using windows auth so I had to add
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), options =>
{
options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
})
.Build();
And when I use the byte buffer method it really tanks the speed of the download like 10x even more. So I just use
zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile and it seems way faster.
If there is anyreason not to use that method let me know.
But the main idea of how to connect to a hub is great!! Oh yeah I changed the js UpdateProgress to Recieve
